# Yii. Change URL based on model parameter value

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I would like to use the same model "Work" for handling similar CRUD operations for "Services" and "Markets" pages. There is a column in the Work mysql table called "category". If category is "service", then I would like the Index to show list of Services that are stored in the Work table. Similarly for the "Markets" page.

I would need two urls for the same Model (in the menu and create/ update operations etc.). How can I set this up in the URL Manager?

'services/create/' => 'work/create?&category="services"',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
array(
    //put it first so it has highest priority
    'services/create' => 'work/create/category/services',
    //other rules follow
)
```

Then your function in your controller would look like this:

```
public function actionCreate($category) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. I have                
'services' => 'work/index/category/services',
'areas' => 'work/index/category/areas',
'services/update/<id>' => 'work/update/category/services',
'areas/update/<id>' => 'work/update/category/areas',
'services/create' => 'work/create/category/services',
'areas/create' => 'work/create/category/areas',                
'services/<id>' => 'work/view/category/services',
'areas/<id>' => 'work/view/category/areas',

and I am able to catch 'services' or 'areas' in the controller. Is there an easier way to do this? It really helped. Thanks.

Comment: Not really because you aren't using the traditional method of using the controller name in your url. If you were fine with using urls like "work/services/create" and "work/services" as the url then yes it could be a lot easier.